# Two column comparasion and return the adjacent column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in pandas

```
  T1         A     T2       P
0 n1        a1     n2       p1  
1 n2        a2     n4       p2
2 n3        a3     n5       p3
..
```

In the task, the values in 'T1' column needs to compared with all the values in 'T2'. If there are any matches (maximum there would be only 1 match), their value along with the adjacent 'A' value to 'T1', 'P' value to 'T2' needs to be written in a new csv file.

The new csv file looks like this for the above data frame:

```
T         A        P
n2        a2       p1*
```

Could someone please help me on how to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can do a `merge`:

```
print (df[["T1", "A"]].merge(df[["T2", "P"]], left_on="T1", right_on="T2")
                      .drop("T1", 1).rename(columns={"T2":"T"}))

    A   T   P
0  a2  n2  p1
```

Comment: Nice one again !!! I think i will have to follow you :)

Comment: You should follow the answerers on [top voted pandas questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas?tab=Votes). Those are canonical answers that everyone learns from including me.

Comment: sure, mentor !! :)